# Entity Framework cancel added/deleted items at EntityCollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class created by the entity framework (`Document`). It has a collection of another class (`FileInfo`).

```cs
/// <summary>
/// No Metadata Documentation available.
/// </summary>
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="DocumentManagerModel", Name="DocumentContainer")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class DocumentContainer : EntityObject
{
    ...

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("DocumentManagerModel", "FK__FileInfo__00000000000018FA", "FileInfo")]
    public EntityCollection<FileInfo> FileInfoes
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<FileInfo>("DocumentManagerModel.FK__FileInfo__00000000000018FA", "FileInfo");
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null))
            {
                ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<FileInfo>("DocumentManagerModel.FK__FileInfo__00000000000018FA", "FileInfo", value);
            }
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

The user now can add or delete a item to the collection (`FileInfos`) through the gui. The gui form has a cancel button. How can I manage to reset all the changes at the collection?

Comment: You can copy the entire `FileInfos` collection and save its initial state. Then you can use this copy to revert changes and make rollback if user press 'cancel'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you didn't call `dbcontext.SaveChanges()` nothing is saved into the database. When they click the cancel button I'd just dispose the dbcontext and create a new one if I were you.

Calling

```
dbcontext.Entry(myEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(dbcontext.Entry(myEntity).OriginalValues); 
dbcontext.Entry(myEntity).State = EntityState.UnChanged;
```

should also do the trick.